# What Should I Do If My Game Is Rejected for Not Displaying the Welcome Banner After a User Has Signed In?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

After the Game Service and IAP SDKs of HMS Core are integrated, I submitted my game for review, but it was rejected by Huawei for not displaying the welcome banner at the top of the game after the sign-in API is called for my game with a HUAWEI ID signed in. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the welcome banner is not displayed after a HUAWEI ID has signed in to the game, check the fault:

1. In the game/app launch phase, add code to the `onCreate` method of `Application` to register the callback listener of the activity. For details, please refer to the [guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/game-start-0000001050123475?ha_source=hms1).

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
     @Override
     public void   onCreate(){
           super.onCreate();
           HuaweiMobileServicesUtil.setApplication(this);
     }
 }
```

2. Before compilation, ensure that the name of the `Application` class, for example, `android:name=".MyApplication"`, has been configured in the `application` element in the app's manifest file.

Answer (score -2):

Try making the display banner for the game before other users try using it